# Drawing the position indicator on the image

Tags: java, processing

so, here is the question, i need to draw the position indicator corresponding to my hand position and then perform some manipulations on an image

here is the screen capture: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZl26.jpg]

the left half of the screen is the image, and the right half of the screen is my camera,
the program will draw the position indicator corresponding to my hand position,
my problem is that the cursor cannot be disappeared and it will draw many times!

here is the code:

```
import gab.opencv.*;
import processing.video.*;
import java.awt.*;

PImage img;
PImage select;
PImage cur;

OpenCV opencv;
Capture cam;

int prevPositionX, prevPositionY, currPositionX, currPositionY;
int mode = -1; //mode 1 = s (select) mode 2 = c (copy) mode 3 = d (draw)
int select_ind = -1;

//store every dectected things
Rectangle[] hand;

//store the biggest hand
Rectangle bhand;


void setup() {
    size(1280, 480);

    img = loadImage("test.jpg");
    cur  = loadImage("cursor.png");
    stroke(255,10,0); 

    opencv = new OpenCV(this, 640, 480);
    opencv.loadCascade("aGest.xml");
    cam = new Capture(this, 640, 480);
    cam.start();

    image(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    }


  void draw(){  
  if (cam.available()==true) {
    cam.read();
  }

  opencv.loadImage(cam);
  hand = opencv.detect();

  pushMatrix();
  scale(-1.0, 1.0);
  image(cam, -1280, 0);
  popMatrix();

int handcount = -1;
int handsize = -1;

  //calculate the biggest hand
  for( int i=0; i < hand.length; i++ ) {
    if(handsize <  (hand[i].width * hand[i].height)){
      handsize = hand[i].width * hand[i].height;
      handcount = 1;
      bhand = hand[i];      
    }
  }

  if(handcount > 0){
      rect(1280 - bhand.x, bhand.y, -bhand.width, bhand.height);
      noFill(); 

      //draw the position indicator   
      image(cur, 480 - bhand.x, bhand.y, 16, 16);   

      prevPositionX = currPositionX;
      prevPositionY = currPositionY;
      currPositionX = 480 - bhand.x + 4;
      currPositionY = bhand.y;

      //select mode
      if (mode == 1){
      }

      //copy mode
      else if (mode == 2){
      }

      //draw mode
      else if (mode == 3){
        line(prevPositionX,prevPositionY,currPositionX,currPositionY);
      }
  }    
}


void keyPressed(){
    if(key=='s'||key=='S')
    mode = 1;

    else if(key=='c'||key=='C')
    mode = 2;

    else if(key=='d'||key=='D')  
    mode = 3;

    else if(key=='i'||key=='I')
    image(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    }



void keyReleased(){
    if(select_ind > -1 && mode == 2){ 
    //to be done

    }

    mode = -1;
    }
```

i am working with the drawing mode which is to draw a line on the image,
and i know the problem but i do not know how to solve it,
i need to add this : image(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height); to the first
of draw() function, but the line will also be deleted. i want to keep
the line like the screen capture.
Please give me a hand and sorry for the bad english. Thanks

Comment: What is `Capture`? If this is done in Java Swing, I will consider reviewing [How to Use Layered Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to persist just part of the draw, you need to redraw it every frame, while still "clearing" the background using `image(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height)`. This means store coordinates of lines and redraw it every time, also note that you can hide the cursor... SomeThing like this:

```java
// YOU GOT ADD (CLICK) AT LEAST 2 POINTS TO SEE IT WORKING ;)

ArrayList<PVector> positions  = new ArrayList<PVector>();

void setup(){
  size(600, 600);

  //if you don't want to see the cursor...
  noCursor();    
}

void draw(){
  //clear screen
  background(255);

  //always draw at mousePosition
  //a "custom cursor"
  //that will not persist as screen is beeing cleared
  fill(200,80,220);
  noStroke();
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);

  stroke(80);
  PVector prevP = null;

  for (PVector p:positions) {
    if(prevP != null) {
      line(prevP.x, prevP.y, p.x, p.y);
    }

    prevP = p.get();
  }
}

void mouseClicked() {
  positions.add(new PVector(mouseX, mouseY));
}
```

**EDIT:**
Also you can use PGraphics as layers to persist just part of the drawing without redrawing all the stuff over and over... :)